# Using unicode characters in html page (Armenian translation)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I have a page where the content is in Armenian.

My question is, What steps do I need to take in order for the symbols to display correctly?

Currently, something like

```
"Պատվերների համար կարող եք զանգահարել"
```

produces

```
"ÕŠÕ¡Õ¿Õ¾Õ¥Ö€Õ¶Õ¥Ö€Õ« Õ°Õ¡Õ´Õ¡Ö€ Õ¯Õ¡Ö€Õ¸Õ² Õ¥Ö„ Õ¦Õ¡Õ¶Õ£Õ¡Õ°Õ¡Ö€Õ¥Õ¬".
```

As it stands right now, my page is pure HTML but I will be incorporating features built on Ruby/Rails and will also be translating that content in Armenian.

I have been reading about Rails Internationalization, but have never used it nor am I sure if that is the best/easiest option?

Comment: Looking at another thread, I found that setting my meta tag to show utf-8 did the trick: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: the physical file itself must be UTF8 on the server hard drive !

Answer (score 3):

In my case  works fine. Or you can use online converters to convert Armenian symbols to Unicode (in case of ANSI).

Comment: Good solution, Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Should be working by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the `<head>` of your HTML File and by using a font that supports Armenian Characters.

If you want to use a Webfont for this, for example Noto Sans from Google Webfonts should do the job.

Use this in your CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansarmenian.css);

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Armenian', serif;
}
```

Found here: https://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess

Answer (score 1):

At first use "Brackets", then

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Ինչ-որ կոդ </title>
</head>
<body>
Պատվերների համար կարող եք զանգահարել
</body>
</html>
```